# Plot discrete points on a graph TI-BASIC

Tags: graph, ti-basic

I've been delving into the TI-BASIC programming language on my Ti-89 Titanium but it appears the online documentation is very scarce, so I'm kind of stumbling around in the dark while trying to learn the syntax. I've already worked through the basic concepts presented in the [guidebook](https://education.ti.com/en/us/products/calculators/graphing-calculators/ti-89-titanium/downloads/guidebooks) on programming, but they seem far from complete/descriptive.

For starters, how may I plot discrete points as one may do in statistics (i.e. a value at every integer on the x-axis)?

So far I see that I may append generated points to the end of a list as [note that "->" will mean "STO"]

```
newList(5)->total
Disp total
```

displays a list like `{0. 0. 0. 0. 0.}`. Now, if I write a for loop to iterate over the list like

```
for i,.2,1.,.2
 i->total[i]
```

I should have a list like `{.2 .4 .6 .8 1.}`. Now here the problem arises: say I want to plot these points on the graph screen against the integers on the x-axis, starting at x=1. How do I do this? Specifically, I want to plot the points

(1., .2), (2., .4), (3., .6), (4., .8), (5., 1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your attempt is that you attempted to store your values at the .2, .4, .6, and .8 slots in the list, which do not exist.  To fix this problem, do:

```
:for i, 1, 5, 1
:i*0.2 -> total[i]
```

This should produce your list.  To plot this, use the `Plot1` (or `Plot2` or `Plot3`) command to plot this:

```
:Plot1(Scatter, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, total, .)
```

The first param is the type of plot, the second is the list of x values (im not sure if what I did would work, you may have to create a list of x values and input that).  The third is the y values, and the final is the mark on the graph.  I know that there are three available in the catalog on the Ti-84 family calculators. I'm not sure about your Ti-89, but the symbols available on the Ti-84 are a • at the point, a + at the point, and a(n) ○ around the point. Good luck with your project.